# How do I quote the special character + and a one-letter-plus-two-digit string?

Tags: perl

I have the following text to modify in Perl:

```
"tti_d01_DA_" + it + "H"
```

In my replacement text, I want to replace `d01` with a variable `${Dom}` and `DA` with `${simul}`, so that I have:

```
"tti_${Dom}_${simul}_" + it + "H"
```

I have tried the following searches for the original string:

```
s/"tti_.\d{2}_\w+_" \+ \w+ \+ "H"/"tti_${Dom}_${simul}_" + it + "H"/;
s/"tti_(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]) (?=.*[_]) \w+ (?=.*[_]) (?=.*["])\s(?=.*[+])\s\w+\s(?=.*[+])\s"H"/"tti_${Dom}_${simul}_" + it + "H"/;
```

I thought this should be a very simple issue, but somehow I am not able to get it. Both the above do not find what I am looking for.

Comment: Do you try to replace with literal `${Dom}` or his value? If it's value, what is the value?

Comment: ${Dom} is a variable, so it will be d01 or d02 and similarly ${simul} is a variable DA or NODA, it has to remain it and H, H.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba  If you need literal `${Dom}` in the final string (after the regex), then you need to escape those `$` in the regex.  See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in my tests

```
s/"tti_\K d[0-9]{2}_\w+_"(?= \+ it \+ "H")/\${Dom}_\${simul}_/
```

In the original same string there is `DA` pattern, which as comments say can be `NODA` instead. That is captured by `\w+` above, following the attempt in the question.  However, if it can *only* be either `DA` or `NODA`, as a comment says, then one may want to use `DA|NODA` (instead of `\w+`), so that the match fails for anything else. Or something in between, like `[A-Z]+`.

This is a choice to make that depends on the context -- either make a pattern as restrictive as possible, to protect from unexpected (and unacceptable) input, or make it more permissive to catch more of what is acceptable.

The question doesn't say what happens with shown attermps but here are some comments.

The only outright problem that I readily see is the `$`s in the replacement side, which *have to* be escaped if they are to be used as literal characters, otherwise it will look for variables `$Dom` and `$simul`.<sup>†</sup> (But then `strict` wouldn't let the program compile because there are no such variables -- do you have `use strict;` in your program?)

Next, I use [`\K` lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5CK) so that all that's been matched up to that point is dropped (from `$&` and so kept in the string) and doesn't have to be re-entered in the replacement side.

In the same vein, I use a [lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) `(?=...)` for patterns that follow what needs to be replaced.  That is an *assertion* (zero-length), which doesn't consume anything, so those sub patterns don't need to be replaced into the string either.

These two tweaks 'lighten' the replacement side (but are not necessary).

---

Test program

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $str = shift// q("tti_d01_DA_" + it + "H");
#say $str; 

$str =~ s/"tti_\Kd[0-9]{2}_\w+_"(?= \+ it \+ "H")/\${Dom}_\${simul}_/;

say $str;
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  It appears from a comment that the problem may have been with variable naming: there are arrays `@Dom` and `@simul` in the program, and the replacements need be `$Dom[index]` (etc).

If that indeed is the whole problem then having `use strict;` at the beginning would've caught it.  It would not let the program even compile and it would report that the variable `$Dom` does not exist.

Having `use strict;` and `use warnings;` is directly helpful, and really necessary I'd say. No wonder that they are enabled by default by many tools and, finally, in newer Perls.

Comment: Thanks @zdim. DA is also a variable. Sometimes it will find there DA and other times it will be NODA. The above line does not work on my ubuntu 18.04. When I write $line=s/"tti_\K d[0-9]{2}_DA_"(?= \+ it \+ "H")/\${Dom}_\${simul}_/; and then print "$line\n"; it prints nothing

Comment: @ZiloreMumba  Cannot write `$line = s/../../;` -- that `$line` gets a number of substitutions made. (I test this in a program and it works? I will add the program) I don't understand the comment about DA -- the question says that DA need be replaced by `${simul}` (as a literal string) ... yes?

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Added a test program to the answer.  That `q()` is the operator form of single quotes, so it just quotes the string inside `()`.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Yes this last one works, but can we make DA a variable? It has to be replaced by $simul.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba "_make DA a variable_"   -- oh, you mean it doesn't have to be `DA~, it can be `NODA` (or some other string instead)? OK.  What can it be -- just word-characters (`a-zA-Z0-9_`)?

Comment: There are only two DA, NODA

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Changed `DA` in the pattern to `\w+`.  (Followed by `_`)  If that `DA` can only be characters (and not `_`) then better use `[a-zA-Z]`, and add `0-9` if it can have numbers as well

Comment: @ZiloreMumba  "_There are only two DA, NODA_"  -- then you may want to use `DA|NODA`, so if anything else comes up it won't match at all?

Comment: @ZiloreMumba Updated the answer.  See the comment -- you have options there.  Can use `\w+` as you attempted, or `[A-Z]+` (only capitals) ... or `DA|NODA`, if it is indeed strictly that.

Comment: Thanks problem solved. $str =~ s/"tti_\Kd[0-9]{2}_[a-zA-Z]_"(?= \+ it \+ "H")/$Dom[$jj]_$simul[$kk]_" + it + "H")/; works. Sorry I did not mention this. In my long script there \@Dom and \@simul defined. What are being replaced are actually $Dom[$kk] and $simul[$jj]. My appreciation to zdim. I half spent half a day on this. Thanks for giving me rest.

Comment: @ZiloreMumba So there are `@Dom` and `@simul` in the program, but _not_ `$Dom`, and that was the problem?  In Perl, `@Dom` is an array variable (can store multiple values) while `$Dom` is a practically unrelated scalar variable (single value).  If you have `use strict;` in your programs it forces you to always "declare" variables when they are introduced (`my @Dom...` etc) -- and it yells when you use a variable that actually was never declared!  That's very very useful.  We make mistakes and type in variable names which don't exist -- but `use strict;` catches it.  I added a comment

Answer (score 3):

The regexp pattern you are using is correct.

However, `$` is special in double-quote string literals, which include the second part of s///. Just escape them.

Always use `use strict; use warnings;` or equivalent as it would caught this error!

In other words, all you need to do is replace

```perl
s/"tti_.\d{2}_\w+_" \+ \w+ \+ "H"/"tti_${Dom}_${simul}_" + it + "H"/;
```

with

```perl
s/"tti_.\d{2}_\w+_" \+ \w+ \+ "H"/"tti_\${Dom}_\${simul}_" + it + "H"/;
```

Demo:

```
$ perl -Mv5.10 -we'
   $_ = q{"tti_d01_DA_" + it + "H"};
   s/"tti_.\d{2}_\w+_" \+ \w+ \+ "H"/"tti_\${Dom}_\${simul}_" + it + "H"/;
   say;
'
"tti_${Dom}_${simul}_" + it + "H"
```